# Push from GitLab to Azure

Tags: git, azure, continuous-integration, gitlab

At the moment I have an *on premise* `GitLab Server` that has access to internet but it is **not accessible from outside** and I want him to be able to push changes to an `Azure Webapp`.

I found [this](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/auto-deploying-to-azure-app-services-from-gitlab/) that shows a way to automate Azure **pulling** from GitLab, but since it's not accessible from the outside it would be impossible to setup. There is any way where the GitLab server **pushes**(publishes) the commits to master into an `Azure webapp`?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

**Edit:** Repository Mirroring seemed like a good solution but [looks like](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18732) it's a `Gitlab EE` feature.

Comment: Can you setup gitlab-ci? In that way Azure would conntect to gitlab, not Gitlab to Azure. You can run your custom script from gitlab-ci.

Comment: Would gitab-ci require to be port forwarded and accesible from the outside? There is any docs about the setup of the custom script thingy?

Comment: Why is pushing not working? Simply add the Azure-Repo as a remote on your git server (possibly a local copy of the gitlab repo), and then push to that repo from your git server.

Comment: @MartinNyolt I said pulling was not an option, I was not aware I could add the Azure Repo to my gitlab

Comment: @MartinNyolt Isn't Repository Mirroring a GitLab EE only feature?

Comment: You could manually set up [custom hooks in GitLab](http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/custom_hooks.html), too. But this probably requires hooks on both your git server (push to azure) and hooks on your webapp (whatever is required to tell an azure webapp that it has been updated, however I have no idea about azure).

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this, via a stage in your CI process, is to extract the per site credential, then you can push using git remote functionality. I was able to do this via Azure CLI 2.0

## Extract username and Password site-credentials from this new app

```
az appservice web deployment list-site-credentials --name $CI_PROJECT_NAME --resource-group $CI_PROJECT_NAME | jq -r '.publishingUserName' >> username
az appservice web deployment list-site-credentials --name $CI_PROJECT_NAME --resource-group $CI_PROJECT_NAME | jq -r '.publishingPassword' >> password
```

#Store username and pass as variables

```
user=$(cat username)
pass=$(cat password)
```

## Staging bits - Ugly AF (should be artifacts based)

```
mkdir staging
mv * staging/
cd staging
git init
git add -A
git -c user.name="Runner" -c user.email="runner@local.com" commit -m "Sample git msg"
git remote add azure "https://${user}:${pass}@$CI_PROJECT_NAME.scm.azurewebsites.net/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}-$$CI_PROJECT_NAME.git"
git remote -v
git push -f azure master
cd ..
rm -rf staging
```

This is not pretty, please by all means improve on this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't knew that we could set user and password in the URL. You can "secure" this by storing the username and password in CI/CD variables.

Answer (score 0):

If Azure machine can connect to GitLab, you can setup GitLab CI runner that will get changes from GitLab and run your custom script. This way GitLab doesn't have to talk to Azure, Azure will automatically pull changes from GitLab. Any recent GitLab version bundles GitLab-CI service that you can enable in your project. More on [CI-runner configuration here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/README.md) and [GitLab-CI](https://about.gitlab.com/gitlab-ci/).

Comment: He explicitly said *pulling* is not an option.

Comment: I might be able to forward the gitlab though a non standard port. If I do that, Azure would be able to *pull* from it?